# Lamar AddInstances with ServiceRegistry

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, ioc-container, lamar

I have a dotnet core website setup with Lamar, I have the following method in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ServiceRegistry services)
{
  ...
}
```

I want to use AddInstances() as described in the documents at https://jasperfx.github.io/lamar/documentation/ioc/registration/registry-dsl/

**Add Many Registrations with For().AddInstances()**

```
// registry is a StructureMap Registry object
registry.For<IService>().AddInstances(x =>
{
    // Equivalent to For<IService>().Add<ColorService>().....
    x.Type<ColorService>().Named("Red").Ctor<string>("color").Is("Red");

    // Equivalent to For<IService>().Add(new ColorService("Yellow"))......
    x.Object(new ColorService("Yellow")).Named("Yellow");

    // Equivalent to For<IService>().Use(() => new ColorService("Purple"))....
    x.ConstructedBy(() => new ColorService("Purple")).Named("Purple");

    x.Type<ColorService>().Named("Decorated").Ctor<string>("color").Is("Orange");
});
```

However, AddInstances() does not exist, I get the following error

> 'ServiceRegistry.InstanceExpression' does not contain
>   a definition for 'AddInstances' and no accessible extension method
>   'AddInstances' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ServiceRegistry.InstanceExpression' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
services.For<IService>().AddInstances(x =>
{
 ...

 });
```

Is this in another namespace? does it only exist on a StructureMap Registry object as per the example, if so how do I get that from the injected ServiceRegistry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the method has been deprecated as you can simply do...

```
services.For<IService>().Add<Service1>().Named("1");
services.For<IService>().Add<Service2>().Named("2");
```